# I'm getting the error in curl when trying to POST an excel file in ServiceNow Instance

Tags: curl, servicenow-rest-api

I'm getting the following error in curl
{"error":{"message":"Invalid content-type. Supported request media types for this service are: [multipart/form-data]","detail":null},"status":"failure"}

Even though I'm using the content type as mutlipart/form-data.

This is my curl command

curl "https://dev74812.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/upload" --request POST --header "Accept:application/json" --header "Authorization:basic YWRtaW46NUN3OD1qSU4hb3BC --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F table_name=sys_data_source' -F 'table_sys_id=42c970f82fc175102a9ad5ccf699b695' -F 'uploadFile="C:\Users\tsiva\Desktop\users.xlsx"'